# XSLT code for traversal

Tags: xml, xslt

I have requirement to print the first child node of two different parent nodes.
I have two nodes in XML as below. I have added only a part of my xml code:

```
<UserValue title="project_variants" value="">
    <UserList id="id19" type="list">
    <Item value="LTD3,A"></Item>
    <Item value="LTD4,A"></Item>
    <Item value="PRODUCTION,B"></Item></UserList>
</UserValue>
<UserValue>
<UserList id="id11" type="list">
    <Item value="1 EACH"></Item>
    <Item value="2 EACH"></Item>
    <Item value="3 EACH"></Item>
</UserList>
```

Expected output:

LTD3 A 1 EACH

LTD4 A 2 EACH

PRODUCTION B 3 EACH

Please help me in thi

Comment: "*print the first child node of two different parent nodes.*" That's not what your output shows. It seems you want  to print each item with its corresponding (i.e. in the same position) item from the other branch. The question is will there always be exactly the same number of items in each branch.

Comment: Your input is still not valid XML. And you have not answered my question. For someone who wants to be helped, you are sure going about it wrong.

Comment: i am new to XSLT, with some reference code i have done this.which i had posted. but the required output is as above . please let me know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

The xml you have posted seems to be invalid
Assuming the xml is like this

```
<UserValue title="project_variants" value="">
<UserList id="id19" type="list">
    <Item value="LTD3,A"></Item>
    <Item value="LTD4,A"></Item>
    <Item value="PRODUCTION,B"></Item>
</UserList>

<UserList id="id11" type="list">
    <Item value="1 EACH"></Item>
    <Item value="2 EACH"></Item>
    <Item value="3 EACH"></Item>
</UserList>
</UserValue>
```

You can try something like this 
iterate on first group using for-each 
maintain a variable with value equal to current position
{
    iterate on second group using for-each and select the node with position equal            to the var defined in the above loop
}